# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

i'am new to Typescript and using VSCode.

Getting following Error:

***[ts] Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'.
(parameter) action: void**

Code:

```
  loadItems() {
    return this.Apiname.find()
        .map(
        (data) => console.log("data:", data)
        )
        .map(
        payload => ({
            type: 'LOAD_ITEMS',
            payload: payload
        },
        )
        )
        .subscribe(
        action => this._store.dispatch(action)//Error
        );
};
```

Any help will be very helpfull.

Comment: The first `.map` callback does not return anything, try changing it to `.map(  (data) => { console.log("data:", data); return data; } )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `map` statement contains trailing **`,`**, which could be the problem. I'd adjust the code like that:

```
return this.Apiname.find()
    .do( (data) => console.log("data:", data) )
    .map(
        payload => ({
            type: 'LOAD_ITEMS',
            payload: payload
        //},)
        })
    )
    .subscribe(
        action => this._store.dispatch(action) // no error
    );
```

now `action` is of type `{ type: string, payload: ... }`

NOTE: for side effects, like printing with `console.log`, ReactiveX provides  **`.do`** operator - see http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html

Comment: Great to see that ;)